# What is the size limit for a message send to Mockable.io?

Tags: json, http

I am running into some trouble using mockable.io. Sometime a message gets a 500 internal server error with message 'The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.'. It seems that the problem is the size of the message. If I remove some data the call succeeds.

I tried contacting their support but it leads to a non existing UserVoice page (https://mockable.uservoice.com/).

So I was wondering if anybody know what the size limit is for mockable.